# geth in private network throws Out of memory even after using 8 GB RAM + 100 GB swapfile

Tags: go-ethereum

I am testing a private network for last few weeks. The block height has reached around 2,81,000 and now suddenly the memory usage of my server instance has shooted up TOO High and the `geth` process gets killed immediately after the 8GB memory is exhausted.

To resolve this I created a **100GB swapfile** on the server and **all the memory was exhausted** and then again the process was killed, saying "out of memory".

Once I start geth (private chain with network id xxxxx), **even when mining is stopped the memory usage starts to grow at 100mb/sec eating up all the RAM and the Swapfile**

**UPDATE**

After researching for around 12 hours, An important thing is detected that  it occurs only when I open the `rpc port 8546`, If start geth on any other rpc port, geth is satisfied with approx 550 MB RAM.

**IS IT A DoS Attack?**

Comment: are you using Proof of Work in your network? and do you need to do so for any particular reason or could you swap to a less computationally-expensive option such as Clique?

Comment: can you suggest how? and I am sure there is something wrong with my system as I know it will use up whatever amount of memory is given

Comment: What're you setting `geth`s cache too? Try forcing a limit say `--cache=4192`

Comment: I am not explicitly setting `geth` 's cache. Setting --cache 4192, or even 2048, I tried every option but does not help. However please also check my update in the question.

Comment: have you fiddled with the parameters in the block-difficulty calculation?

Comment: Not actually it worked fine untile block Number 2,81,000

Comment: Is server open to public internet ? If it is, I would put a reverse proxy in front of geth to dump all incoming requests. It an indeed be some automated request to find nodes where account has been unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

If it happened to you as well, The probability is that you are opening your port on `http://0.0.0.0`.

Instead while running `geth`, use --rpcaddr as 'localhost'. or open your http endpoint on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: what is the effect for you after using this solution? thanks

Comment: the effect was that the problem was solved. @Rafid. Please give me updates about could you solve this issue  ? in case you are still facing it after changing the endpoint to 127.0.0.1, please let me know.